# Programmatically Filling a Multi-Column ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm looking to fill a UserForm with a multi-column ListBox to choose from. The ListBox columns are filled with data stored in custom class modules objects (Work Requests & Component). I've made my logic as clear as I can, looking for help on the correct way to implement this.

I get the error

> Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid
>   Property array index.

, with the debugger highlighting the line `UserForm.Show`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5
    ListBox1.ColumnWidth = “100;100;100;100;100;”

    Dim i as Integer
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 to (wrArraySize - 1)
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = WorkRequests(i + 1).WorkRequestNumber
            .List(i, 1) = WorkRequests(i + 1).Product
            .List(i, 2) = WorkRequests(i + 1).ComponentName
            .List(i, 3) = WorkRequests(i + 1).NumberPiecesCompleted
            .List(i, 4) = WorkRequests(i + 1).NumberPiecesTotal
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Furthermore, if you have an extra moment to spare, I then need to know how to references all the selected ListBox entries (i.e. using CTRL + Click to select non-adjacent items). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below simple code first. If it works fine, then check your arrays and other references

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "20;20;20;20;20;"

    Dim i As Integer
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To 5
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = i
            .List(i, 1) = i
            .List(i, 2) = i
            .List(i, 3) = i
            .List(i, 4) = i
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

For debugging: the debugger is apt to return to the caller modul in case of an error within an object modul, that may be the reason for stopping on line `UserForm.Show`. You could try to set something like `On Error Resume Next` to override the default errorhandler within the modul (just for testing) to catch the bug.

For managing multiple selection:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next
```

N.b.: for deleting selected items you need to reverse the loop because .ListCount is changing, so

```
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 to Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Listbox1.RemoveItem(i)
    End If
Next
```